# how to implement pcre command filter and postmap on postfix

Tags: postfix, pcre

i am using `postfix 3.3.0`
i have in `main.cf`

```
smtpd_command_filter = pcre:/etc/postfix/command_filter
```

in `comman_filter`

```
/^(RCPT\s+TO:\s*<(.*)@domaina.com>)/  RCPT TO:<$2@domainb.com>
```

whene querying `postmap -q "RCPT TO: <user9@domaina.com>" pcre:/etc/postfix/command_filter`
it works just fine

output: `RCPT TO: <user9@domainb.com>`

i have executed  `postmap /etc/postfix/command_filter` and `restarted postfix`

and still no effect on postfix smtp telnet remote hist and send  rcpt command

Maybe I’m missing something.

```
It has to be done this way not by hash maps redirect domain
```

Comment: Why are you using the [`smtpd_command_filter`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_command_filter) in the first place? It is *a last-resort tool to work around client commands that break interoperability with the Postfix SMTP server*. There are better options for aliases.

Comment: @EsaJokinen thanks for the advice in fact i don’t want to use maps hash domain redirect  because I’m using transport and it’s long story basicly i want to do two transport same domain it has to be done in rcpt command rewrite when postfix’s smtp telnet the remote host and sends rcpt command

Comment: It still sure sounds like an XY problem.